# How to find nonmatching colnames in 2 dataframes?

Tags: r, set-difference

I have 2 data frames with colnames as dates.eg:2020-01-01, 2020-01-02 and so on.

Some dates are missing from the second dataframe, hence different column length. I want to find out which dates are missing in the second so I can remove them from the first.
I used dplyr setdiff but it throws error: `x` and `y` are not compatible.
How do i resolve this?

Comment: `setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))` will show you the ones that are in `df1` but not `df2`. Or you can get the names in common with `intersect(names(df1), names(df2))`

Comment: Thanks this works. I created an object with the colnames and was using it with setdiff. hence it was throwing error.

Comment: Why you got the error remains completely opaque. Need code.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set. An effective way to include one is dput(). https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput. If your object is a data frame and is long, df |> head() |> dput()